# Vagrant windows on windows config.vm.boot_timeout not applied

Tags: vagrant

I'm using sysprep'd images so the boot time is very long for each instance. I have been suspicious that config.vm.boot_timeout was not working in VirtualBox but could not find the value in use in the debug. This morning I tried Hyper-V and it reports the wait time, and it is not that I'm trying to set. I've recreated the scenario with a very small Vagrantfile (i.e. without the VirtualBox provider and all my provisioners).

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'cdaf/WindowsServerStandard'
  config.vm.box_check_update = false
  config.vm.guest = :windows
  config.vm.communicator = 'winrm'
  config.vm.boot_timeout = 600 # 10 minutes
  config.vm.provider 'hyperv' do |hyperv, override|
    hyperv.memory = 1024
    hyperv.cpus = 2
  end
end
```

Here is the output from vagrant up (note the Timeout: 120 seconds)

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'hyperv' provider...
==> default: Verifying Hyper-V is enabled...
==> default: Configured startup memory is 1024
==> default: Configured cpus number is 2
==> default: Importing a Hyper-V instance
    default: Cloning virtual hard drive...
    default: Creating and registering the VM...
    default: Successfully imported a VM with name: WindowServerStandardGUI
==> default: Starting the machine...
==> default: Waiting for the machine to report its IP address...
    default: Timeout: 120 seconds
Hyper-V failed to determine your machine's IP address within the
configured timeout. Please verify the machine properly booted and
the network works. To do this, open the Hyper-V manager, find your
virtual machine, and connect to it.
```

Platform

- Host is Windows 10 with Vagrant 1.9.2
- Guest is Windows Server 2016

Answer (score 1):

I had misinterpreted the "Timeout: 120 seconds" in hyper-v provider, it is not the WinRM timeout, it is the timeout for the VM to report it's IP address, i.e. I can increase this to 4 minutes using

```
hyperv.ip_address_timeout = 240
```

Comment: I've added this to my box construction, the comments are stripped by [AtlasPackage.ps1](https://github.com/cdaf/windows/blob/master/AtlasPackage.ps1) when processing [Vagrantfile](https://github.com/cdaf/windows/blob/master/samples/vagrant-box/Vagrantfile)